# If a mapping $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing, is it an open map?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

If a mapping $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing, is it necessarily an [open map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps)?

i.e. for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$ can we conclude that $g\left((a,b)\right)=\left(g(a),g(b)\right)$? Or do we need that $g$ is continuous for this to be true?

I suspect that the fact that $g$ is strictly increasing is enough to show that it maps open intervals to open intervals, but I am looking for confirmation of this. A basic proof would be nice.

Comment: $g(x) = x$ for $x < 0$ and $g(x) = 1+x$ for $x\ge 0$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\le 0\\
x+1,&\text{if }x>0\;.
\end{cases}$$

Clearly $g$ is strictly increasing, but $g[(-1,1)]=(-1,0]\cup(1,2)$, which is not open.

Comment: Great example. If we also say that $g$ is continuous, then can we conclude that it is an open map?

Comment: @möbius: Yes, since the inverse of $g$ is continuous on $g(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @möbius: Yes, as **user251257** says.

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture is not true. A simple counterexample:
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}x & \quad x < 0,\\
x + 1 &\quad x \geq 0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$f$ then maps the open interval $(-1, 1)$ to $(-1, 0)\cup [1, 2)$, which is not open.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. If the function is strictly increasing and discontinuous, it necessarily means that its image is not open, and then it cannot be an open map (as $\mathbb{R}$ is an open subset of itself).

If $g$ is also continuous, then it is open. This can be shown by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Okay, so what if $g$ was both strictly increasing and continuous? Would it then be an open map?

Comment: @möbius Yes, and I added a line for that to my answer.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and strictly increasing, then it a homeomorphim of $\Bbb R$ with itself, so it is open, of course. @möbius

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not necessarily onto...

Comment: Right. In my mind it was onto. But it will be a homoemorphism with the [necessarily open] interval which is the image.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is this what they mean when they say "open your mind"?

Comment: No, they mean it literally. With a pickax or a bonesaw.